# IIS Server Error on this specific ASPX File

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is the code I made before I realized that the Calender control exists. And please never mind the typo [canlender]!

Somehow this code is making the state of whole IIS [Service Unavailable]. Doing net stop w3svc / net start w3svc won't work too. The hosting provider said [What have you done?]. On my computer (IIS on Win8) would freeze too.

I don't find anything that would make the server unable to service. It's just creating and modifying controls... Any idea about the cause of this problem?

Thanks.

calender.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class member_Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     int currday = 1;
     int len = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
     switch (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).DayOfWeek) {
         case DayOfWeek.Sunday: currday = 1; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Monday: currday = 0; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: currday = -1; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: currday = -2; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Thursday: currday = -3; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Friday: currday = -4; break;
         case DayOfWeek.Saturday: currday = -5; break;
     }
     TableRow tr = new TableRow();
     TableHeaderCell tst;
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Sun"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Mon"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Tue"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Wed"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Thu"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Fri"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tst = new TableHeaderCell(); tst.CssClass = "single_day"; tst.Text = "Sat"; tr.Controls.Add(tst);
     tblCanlender.Controls.Add(tr);
     int a=0;
     while (currday <= len && a++<50)
     {
         tr=new TableRow();
         for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
             TableCell tc = new TableCell();
             if (currday >= 1 && currday <= len) {
                tc.CssClass = "single_day_body";
                tc.Text = currday.ToString();
                tc.Controls.Add(tc);
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = "Add";
                tc.Controls.Add(lnk);
             }
             tr.Controls.Add(tc);
             currday++;
         }
         tblCanlender.Controls.Add(tr);
     }
 }
}
```

calender.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState ="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="calender.aspx.cs" Inherits="member_Default" %>

<style type="text/css">
    .single_day{
           width:80px;
           height:40px;
           background:#DDD;
    }
    .single_day_body{
           width:80px;
           height:80px;
           text-align:left;
           vertical-align:top;
           background:#FFF;
    }
    table, th, tr, td, thead, tbody {
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    a.insertdate, a.insertdate:visited, a.insertdate:link {
        color:gray;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    a.insertdate:hover {
        color:#DDD;
    }
</style>
<asp:Table runat="server" id="tblCanlender" style="width:100%;border:1px solid gray;background:#EEE"></asp:table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tc.Controls.Add(tc);
```

are you sure this is intended? it seems like a circular reference.

Comment: Looks like the IIS is resulting the right error this time. Thank you! ...but the oddness of IIS being frozen after doing this reference... can it be considered as a bug of the server software?

Comment: I guess you could consider it a bug but tbh i wouldn't expect iis to handle this situation differently. It's probably causing a stack overflow because everytime the html for var TC is created the parser will continue with it's child element TC. That can't go on forever :)

Comment: Yeah... I'd liked if ASP.net would have shown the stack overflow error. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: stack overflows and thread exceptions are on my list of unloggable exceptions so i completely aggree that i would like them to be loggable :) ! You're welcome & good luck with the project !